# Let $R$ be a commutative, unital ring and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Prove that if $I$ is prime then $R/I$ is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative, unital ring and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Prove that if $I$ is prime then $R/I$ is an integral domain.

This makes sense, but I'm not sure how to prove it using only the axioms. I know an ideal of $R$ is prime iff $\forall a,b\in R,$ if $ab\in I,$ then $a\in I$ or $b\in I.$ Also, integral domains are commutative, unital, and have no zero divisors. As well, $R/ I$ is the set $\{[a] : a\in R\},$ where $\forall a,b, a\sim b$ iff $a-b \in I.$

> How do I show that commutativity preserved by the quotient ring? Also, how do I show that $R/ I$ is still unital?
>
> Is commutativity preserved because $\forall a, b\in R/I, [a][b]=[ab]=[ba]=[b][a]$?
>
> How do I show that if $a,b\in R$ such that $ab=0,$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$?

Comment: Do you know how multiplication in the quotient is **defined**?  This makes all this a trivial check.

Comment: $R\backslash I$ means the set of elements that are in $R$ but not in $I$. What you mean is $R/I$, the quotient of $R$ by $I$.

Comment: Right.  So can't you check commutativity?

Comment: Also, in your last edit, you want to show that either $a=0$ or $b=0$, not $\neq$.  And you need to show this in the quotient, not in $R$.

Comment: You are correct.